# iOS - sizeWithFont issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I have text "Testing of application". it looks line in cell is

```
"Tesing of 
 Application"
```

I want to add a Asteric right a text. for e.g

```
"Tesing of *
Application"
```

but it show after the width of Label.. I have written the following code.

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(99999,9999);

CGSize textSize = [[_label text] sizeWithFont:_label.font
                                 constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize                                          lineBreakMode:_label.lineBreakMode];


float startX = 2 + textSize.width;
label2.frame = CGRectMake(startX, label2.frame.origin.y, label2.frame.size.width, label2.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: and your problem is?..

Comment: It draw the '*' at the end of the label size. It should be at 70 but it is at 130. and 130 is the label size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `constrainedToSize` you have to pass the size with real height or real width.

Let say you have a label on `300px` width and you want to make the height according to text length you have to use `CGSizeMake(300,9999)`. In this case the `constrainedToSize`method will return you the height need to draw that text.

For getting the width you can set a small height like `20px` to get the width needed to draw the text.